# Java - Priority Queue is showing NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have a class inside the main class named **Prims** and a priority queue of the class type.After I created an instance of the class with its construct, I want to push the object into the queue.Compiled well, But it shows run-time error with **NullPointerException** .Here is the code:

```
package mst.prims;

import java.util.*;

    public class Main {

        /**
         * Minimum Spanning Tree - Prim's Algorithm
         * @author Kaidul
         */
        static final int MAX = 100; 

        static class Prims{
            int u, v, cost;
            Prims(int u, int v, int cost){
                this.u = u;
                this.v = v;
                this.cost = cost;
            }
        }

        static PriorityQueue<Prims> q, q1, q2 = new PriorityQueue<Prims>(MAX);

        public static void main(String[] args)  {


            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                int u, v, cost;
                u = input.nextInt();
                v = input.nextInt();
                cost = input.nextInt();
                Prims temp = new Prims(u, v, cost);

                q.add(temp);
            }
        }

    }
```

Error :

```
1 2
2 3
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at mst.prims.Main.main(Main.java:36)
```

I am new in Java and can't fix it.

Comment: Please show a complete stack trace

Comment: without stack trace expecting help very difficult.

Comment: what is stack trace? Please explain.I am new in java :(

Comment: the error that get printed when you run the program.. the whole text.

Comment: Strange! I got java.lang.ClassCastException when I ran your code!

Comment: The situation you describe is not possible with the code you have posted.

Comment: I have edited my question.Now I post all the program and stack trace

Comment: you are just using 'q' now. try removing q1, q2 for now and atleast for me it does not show the null pointer exception. But you have to implement comparable to make use of priority queue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Javadoc for `PriorityQueue`:

> A priority queue relying on natural ordering also does not permit insertion of non-comparable objects (doing so may result in ClassCastException).

You must implement `Comparable` in `Prims`.  If you intend to use `Prims` in collections you should also override `equals()` and `hashCode()` with implementations appropriate for your object.

Answer (score 3):

It should not give `NullPointerException`, rather it should give `ClassCastException`. Because your class `Prims` does not implement a `Comparable` interface, and hence cannot pushed in `Priority Queue`.

You need to implement `Comparable` and provide the `compareTo` method in your `nested Prims class`

And please use meaningful names for your variables. `u` and `v` seems vague to me, depicting no meaning as to what they represent.

Comment: `  Collections.sort(q, new Comparator<Prims> () {
   public int compare(Prims x, Prims y){
    if(x.cost > y.cost) return 1;
    if(x.cost < y.cost) return -1;
    return 0;
   }
  });` I have created it.Now where to put it?

Comment: @user1658353 You want to sort your priority queue?

Comment: In that case, put it inside your main method, after your for loop ends.

Comment: Wait. you need to change your class declaration to `class Prims implements Comparable<Prims>`

Comment: For me it gives a NullPointerException, not a ClassCastException. The exception is no longer thrown when I implement Comparable.